# can not install tensorflow with with conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I want to use anaconda prompt to install tensorflow but when I run this command: conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow I  got an error:unavailable invalid chanel. You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Can you install any other packages or do you get the same error?

Comment: What is your version of Anaconda?

Comment: Did you ever figure things out?

Answer (score 0):

You could try pip

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: I tried this and can install tensorflow with conda: 1  conda config --remove-key channels
2  conda config --add channels https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/
3 conda config -set show_channel_urls yes

Answer (score 0):

it is better not to install anything with in the system and recommended way is to create an virtual environment

and install whatever you want in the environment

you can look at [here](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/)

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 starting Anaconda Navigator,
    goto'Environments',
    goto button 'Channels' and
    removing the channel
```